# Macro code does not worked out when copy multiple unordered cell range to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to copy some unordered rows from one workbook (File 1), to another workbook (File 2). Here is the code that I already write, fyi the code is in File 1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
    Dim CopyRng As Range, PasteRng As Range
    xTitleId = "For File Internal"
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set CopyRng = Application.Selection
    Set CopyRng = Application.InputBox("Ranges to be copied :", xTitleId, CopyRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Downloads\File 2.xlsx")
    Set sht2 = wkb2.Worksheets(6)

    sht2.Activate
    Set PasteRng = Application.InputBox("Paste to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    CopyRng.Copy
    PasteRng.Parent.Activate

    With sht2.Range(PasteRng.Address)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

When I copy a consecutive range (ex= E20:J24), this code is worked. The problem is when i copy an unordered range (ex= E20:$J21,E23:J24), this code does not worked out. But, when I use this code for copy an unordered range to same worksheet it just worked. I still cannot figure out where is my mistake.

Comment: I don't know if this directly affects your process but xl2013 has a different relationship with workbook 'windows' inside application instances. It would help if you could clarify your xl version number.

Comment: btw i'm using xl version 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy to a direct destination on another worksheet, you lose your formulas and keep the cell formatting so you do not require the xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats or xlPasteFormats operations of the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)¹.

I suggest you break the multiple .PasteSpecial operations into two operations; a [Worksheet.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx) with a distinct destination and a single .PasteSpecial with **xlPasteColumnWidths**.

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
    Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range, xTitleId As String
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook, sht2 As Worksheet

    xTitleId = "For File Internal"
    Set copyRng = Application.Selection
    Set copyRng = Application.InputBox("Ranges to be copied :", xTitleId, copyRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Downloads\File 2.xlsx")
    Set sht2 = wkb2.Worksheets(6)

    sht2.Activate
    Set pasteRng = Application.InputBox("Paste to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    'copy values and formatting
    copyRng.Copy Destination:=pasteRng

    'copy column widths
    With pasteRng
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With
End Sub
```

This works for my xl2010 version 14.0.7165.500 (32-bit). I've had people contradict this practise stating that copy to another workbook actually **does** bring over the formulas but I cannot reproduce that behavior in this version.

---

¹ <sub>See [XlPasteType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) for full list of [Range.PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) operations</sub>